# 2006 Volvo s40 started smoking suddenly

Tags: engine, volvo, s40

Had my car serviced two weeks ago fuel consumption and great and been driving smoothly. Yesterday driving from work it suddenly started smoking terribly. Stop at the gas station checked the oil and it was over filled so assumed it just excess burning of. Then this morning pull it out and checked the oil again and the level is low. Still smokes like crazy if I step on the gass and u can smell its oil burning. Any advice?

Comment: What color is the smoke? And are you sure you checked the oil correctly? Oil doesn't suddenly get really high then in a days time become low. Also, how many miles and which engine in the Volvo?

Comment: Smoke is a white slight blue colour. At the gass station the attending and I both triple checked it. I was way over the full mark. I had driven the car and it was at temperature when switched off. This morning I pulled it out of the garage and then checked it three times and it was at the bottom stripe of the dipstick. 200 000km 2l petrol

Answer (score 2):

Smoke is a white slight blue colour. At the gass station the attending and I both triple checked it. I was way over the full mark. I had driven the car and it was at temperature when switched off. This morning I pulled it out of the garage and then checked it three times and it was at the bottom stripe of the dipstick.

Comment: Wayne are you the same person that posted the question?

Comment: If so click on [contact us](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/contact) and select "I need to merge user profiles" they will combine your registered account with your unregistered account and you will be able to edit and comment on your question.